# Twilio Chat - Can't fetch public channel "services.publicChannels is undefined" unless member of channel

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: "_this6.services.publicChannels is undefined"
    _callee4$/</< webpack:///./node_modules/twilio-chat/browser/client.js?:452
    run webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js?:75
    notify webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js?:92
    flush webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_microtask.js?:18
```

Running version: `"twilio-chat": "^3.3.0"`

Using method `.getChannelBySid(...)` to fetch the channel. Confirmed that I'm using a proper SID.

Additionally, it works when the member that is within the channel is the one fetching the channel. The error only happens if a non-member requests info. I have confirmed that the channel in question has the type `public`, so it should work.

The use case is that all chat admins should have visibility into all chats. The chats are `public` for this reason.

Comment: Chat User can join a public channel, did you try tweaking the [user roles](https://www.twilio.com/console/chat/services/<seriveid>/roles)?

Comment: @Chenna they are all "Channel User"'s and still can't join/view other public channels.